# Importing an Excel Workbook to SQL database with Empty Rows & Columns

Tags: sql, excel, ssis, etl

I have an Excel workbook similar to the posted image that I'm trying to import via SSIS. It has specific formatting like empty columns and rows so when it's imported, it has a lot of NULL values. What is the best approach to importing a workbook like this?

[Screenshot of example workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfH7f.png)

Comment: Which block of the excel report are you trying to import. I see 3 blocks or are you trying to import all the contents in the excel spreadsheet. Is this spreadsheet data from a report?

Comment: Is this format remain same or is it going to be changed?

Comment: I am trying to import all the contents of the spreadsheet. And no not from a report--it's a working document that will have inputs in regards to forecasts.

Comment: Here's a different screenshot of the workbook: https://imgur.com/FCoW7Jg

Comment: Usually you would be loading the underlying data to create a report like this

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a specific area of the excel-sheet, you can use the SQL Command -Data Access Mode in Excel Connecor and use a syntax like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$C4:J10]
```

Example here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/importing-excel-data-into-sql-server-via-ssis-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/#eighth